# Fail to get result with Using readxl and read_excel() - Rogue lines 2 and 3 in .xls

Tags: r, tidyr, readxl

I'm trying to open an .xls which has column names in line 1 but addition parts of the name in lines 2 and 3.  Some cells in line 2 and 3 are blank.

```
library(readxl)
# This doesn't work
read_excel(dest)

# This doesn't work
read_excel(dest, skip = 3, col_names = FALSE)
# ... nor this
read_excel(dest, n_max = 1, col_names = TRUE)

# This works on manually modified file content (lines 2 and 3 deleted)
read_excel('../data/downloaded_FLEET2.xls', sheet = 1) 

# This works on file that was manually converted to xlsx (Note: lines 2 and 3 still present)
read_excel('../data/downloaded_FLEET.xlsx', sheet = 1) 

# This works on file that was manually converted to csv and back into xls (Note: lines 2 and 3 still present)
read_excel('../data/downloaded_FLEET3.xls', sheet = 1)
```

Any ideas?  I really want to avoid any manual intervention.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say read_excel(dest) does not work ? What happens when you try it ?

Comment: The response is "0 rows"

Answer (score 0):

Since .xlsx is working, I would try a different library such as `openxlsx::read.xlsx`.

Comment: The file is downloaded from an url and the native format is .xls

so any change to .xlsx would be manual.  I tried installr::xlsx2csv but without success

Thanks